# PyGame window crashes without running code

Tags: python, pygame

Every time I try running my code in pygame, it loads the window and then freezes and not responding. I've been told that the code doesn't run past the display update loop. I can't figure out what is wrong and it has been very frustrating trying to code without being able to test it. This is for a simple PyGame platformer I'm trying to make for a project in school. This is just the main menu and does include some functions that aren't in this clip of code. I was using VS Code to write the program and it is running on an extension called "Pygame Snippets".
The code is here:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

run = 1
loop = 1

pygame.init()
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))

White = (255,255,255)
DGray = (128,128,128)
LGray = (170,170,170)

DFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",40)
BFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 60)

while loop == 1:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    pygame.display.update()

while run == 1:
    def main_menu():

            Menu1 = 1
            hover_controls = 0
            hover_levels = 0
            hover_quit = 0

            T1 = DFont.render("Level Select", True , White)
            T2 = DFont.render("Controls", True , White)
            T3 = DFont.render("Quit", True , White)
            Title = BFont.render("Maths Platformer", True, White)


            while Menu1 == 1:

                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
                if 220 <= mouse[0] <= 420 and 310<= mouse[1] <= 410:
                    hover_levels == 1

                if 860 <= mouse[0] <= 1060 and 310<= mouse[1] <= 410:
                    hover_controls == 1

                if 540 <= mouse[0] <= 740 and 550 <= mouse[1] <= 650:
                    hover_quit == 1



                for ev in pygame.event.get():
                    if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.QUIT()

                    else:

                        if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                            if hover_levels == 1:
                                levels_menu()

                            if hover_controls == 1:
                                controls_menu()

                            if hover_quit == 1:
                                pygame.quit

            screen.fill((117, 196, 255))

            if hover_levels == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[220,310,200,100])

            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[220,310,200,100])


            if hover_controls == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[860,310,200,100])

            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[860,310,200,100])


            if hover_quit == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[540,550,200,100])

            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[540,550,200,100])


            screen.blit(T1, (270, 360))

            screen.blit(T2, (910, 360))

            screen.blit(T3, (590, 600))

            screen.blit(Title, (570, 180))


        
                
    main_menu()
```

Comment: What do you expect. The loop `while loop == 1:` never terminates, because `loop` is never changed.

Comment: why do You define a function inside a loop? just define it outside and then call, also why are You using two `while` loops?

Comment: I would recommend you to please understand python syntax properly and then try to code this of while loop == 1 like its the why you defined a variable loop as 1 you could define it as true if you define it as 1 it will work but it does not make sense its like u are saying loop = "my_user_name" while loop == "my_user_name" again this code will work but makes no sense there are lots of errors in your like you are using screen instead of Screen please learn python properly then try to code this game i am saying this for your good or in future you will get many more errors I am sorry if u felt bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `while loop == 1:` never terminates, because `loop` is never changed. Reomve this code completely.
`==` is the comparison operator. You have to use the assignment operator when specifying  a variable (e.g.: `hover_levels = 1`).
Python is case sensitive. Hence, you need to make sure that you are using `screen` everywhere (instead of `Screen`).
You must draw the menus in the application loop. Respect the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html).
`pygame.QUIT` is an event type. The name of the "quit" function is [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit).

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

run = 1
#loop = 1

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))

White = (255,255,255)
DGray = (128,128,128)
LGray = (170,170,170)

DFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",40)
BFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 60)

#while loop == 1:
#    pygame.time.delay(100)
#    pygame.display.update()

def main_menu():
    global run

    Menu1 = 1
    
    T1 = DFont.render("Level Select", True , White)
    T2 = DFont.render("Controls", True , White)
    T3 = DFont.render("Quit", True , White)
    Title = BFont.render("Maths Platformer", True, White)

    while Menu1 == 1:

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        hover_controls = 0
        hover_levels = 0
        hover_quit = 0
        if 220 <= mouse[0] <= 420 and 310<= mouse[1] <= 410:
            hover_levels = 1
        if 860 <= mouse[0] <= 1060 and 310<= mouse[1] <= 410:
            hover_controls = 1
        if 540 <= mouse[0] <= 740 and 550 <= mouse[1] <= 650:
            hover_quit = 1

        for ev in pygame.event.get():
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                Menu1 = False
            else:

                if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if hover_levels == 1:
                        levels_menu()
                    if hover_controls == 1:
                        controls_menu()
                    if hover_quit == 1:
                        run = False
                        Menu1 = False

    # Indentation
    #-->|

        screen.fill((117, 196, 255))

        if hover_levels == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[220,310,200,100])
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[220,310,200,100])

        if hover_controls == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[860,310,200,100])
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[860,310,200,100])

        if hover_quit == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,LGray,[540,550,200,100])
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,DGray,[540,550,200,100])

        screen.blit(T1, (270, 360))
        screen.blit(T2, (910, 360))
        screen.blit(T3, (590, 600))
        screen.blit(Title, (570, 180))
        pygame.display.update()

while run == 1:             
    main_menu() 

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
while loop == 1:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

always runs and then runs constantly.  Remove it and put display.update at the end of the menu loop.